# Why am I getting a 500 error even though post request's being sent to DB successfully?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I've come across a very strange error in my console where even though I submit data successfully in the database, I get a 500 error that says:

`POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

This making is sense is beyond me as it just seems illogical.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the post controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, Post $post) {
        // create post
        $createdPost = $request->user()->posts()->create([
            'body' => $request->body
        ]);

        // return response
        return response()->json($post->with('user')->find($createdPost->id));
    }
}
```

Here are routes:

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'TimelineController@index');
    Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@create');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is located in your response line. You are calling the `find()` method in an single model object instead of a [Model class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models), a [Collection object](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections) or a [Relationship object](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships). Check the signalled line:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, Post $post) {

        // ...

        return response()->json($post->with('user')->find($createdPost->id)); // <----
    }
}
```

Try this instead:

```
        return response()->json(Post::with('user')->find($createdPost->id));
        // or even easier:
        return response()->json($createdPost->load('user'));
```

Comment: `return response()->json($createdPost->load('user'));` did it for me!  thank you!  Note: you forgot the `()` in `response`.

Comment: @mrtest gald to help. PS: Thanks for the note, I've fixed the code ;)